How to set up OAuth login using Expo AuthSession with Identity Server 4 in React Native?
I'm trying to set up OAuth login in my React Native app using Expo's AuthSession and Identity Server 4. I've followed the basic setup, but I'm running into issues, and I can't seem to find a comprehensive guide for this specific scenario. Here's the code I have so far:
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as AuthSession from 'expo-auth-session';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

const redirectUri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({
native : sample_name://oauthredirect
});

export default function App() {
  const discovery = AuthSession.useAutoDiscovery('https://demo.identityserver.io');
  const [request, result, promptAsync] = AuthSession.useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: 'sample-clientid',
      redirectUri,
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access', 'roles'],
    },
    discovery
  );

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Login!" disabled={!request} onPress={() => promptAsync()} />
      {result && <Text>{JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)}</Text>}
    </View>
  );
}


Problem

I’m not sure if the configuration is correct or if there’s something I'm missing in setting up the OAuth flow with Identity Server 4.
When I run the app, the button appears, but I’m not sure how to handle the authentication response properly or if there are any additional steps required on the Identity Server side

Questions:

Is the redirectUri correctly configured for Expo?
Do I need to add any specific configurations on Identity Server 4 for this to work?
What are the best practices for handling the OAuth response in a React Native app?

Additional Info:

I'm using Expo in my project, and the OAuth configuration is meant for mobile apps.
The Identity Server is set up with standard configurations.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
